# Shell returned -1073741819

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors

When I run the code below for the problem farmer drama - AIO 2016 (https://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?set=aio16int&problemid=903),

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    //freopen("farmin.txt", "r", stdin);
    //freopen("farmout.txt", "w", stdout);

    int n; cin >> n;
    
    vector<int> p(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> p[i];
    }
    
    int f=p[0], l=p[n-1], i1=0, i2=n-1, c=0;
    while (i1!=i2) {
        if (f==l) {
            --i2; ++i1;
            f = p[i1]; l = p[i2];
            continue;
        }
        if (f<l) {
            ++i1;
            f = f+p[i1];
            c++;
        }
        if (l<f) {
            --i2;
            l = l+p[i2];
            c++;
        }
    }

    cout << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

the terminal returns shell returned -1073741819 even though the logic is perfectly fine. The exact error message is below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (AIO\2016\farmer)
6
1 1 1 1 1 1
shell returned -1073741819
Hit any key to close this window...
```

While if I run a different input such as:

```
8
1 2 2 5 1 3 1 1
```

it runs perfectly fine and returns the correct output: 3.

This has been happening quite frequently but I don't know what is causing it. Could you please help me as this is quite frustrating?

Comment: Looks like a segfault - run your code under a debugger and/or valgrind and fix the bug that causes the segfault.

Comment: maybe you should try `while(i1<i2)` instead of `while(i1!=i2)` - just a wild guess...

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code against AddressSanitizer; you are getting a segmentation fault and the therefore your shell exits with a strange return code.

The problem is with this line:

```
f = p[i1]; l = p[i2];
```

When running your code against the faulty sample provided, `i1` had a value of `6`, which causes an overflow; and `i2` had a value of -1.

Try preventing this by adding another condition in your while loop, such as:

```
while(i1 > -1 && i1 != i2)
```

However I have not tested this, this will prevent the error but I am not sure if it gives the correct answer.